# Ejected Expo app cannot find custom native module in NativeModules

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a React Native app, that was built using Expo, which I then ejected to ExpoKit.

I [followed this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to try to implement a custom native Android module, with a few changes due to the layout of an ejected ExpoKit app. Thus, the `android` directory is laid out as follows:

[image: android directory]

```java
// <workspace>/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/ToastModule.java

package com.reactlibrary;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
    private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

    public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ToastExample";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
        final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
        constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return constants;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void show(String message, int duration) {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
    }

}
```

```java
// <workspace>/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/ToastPackage.java

package com.reactlibrary;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomToastPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new ToastModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

}
```

```java
// <workspace>/android/app/src/main/java/host/exp/exponent/MainApplication.java

package host.exp.exponent;

// other imports

import com.reactlibrary.CustomToastPackage

public class MainApplication extends ExpoApplication implements AppLoaderPackagesProviderInterface<ReactPackage> {

  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        // Needed for `react-native link`
        new MainReactPackage(),

        new KCKeepAwakePackage(),
        new CustomToastPackage()
    );
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

Finally, in my React Native application, I load it like so:

```
// <workspace>/src/utils/native-modules.ts

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

export const { ToastExample } = NativeModules
```

#### Expected result

I would expect `ToastExample` in `native-modules.ts` to return some API that I can interact with, in this case, the methods exposed by the `CustomToastPackage`.

#### Actual result

`ToastExample` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a module declaration on the same path.

```js
// <workspace>/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/index.js
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

const { ToastExample } = NativeModules;

export default ToastExample;
```

Usage

```js
import {
  NativeModules
} from "react-native";
...
const { ToastExample } = NativeModules;
...
ToastExample.show('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT);
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to put it in the same directory as the Java classes? Anyway, I tried it, and it didn't help.

Comment: This is actually the way I'm using it, and I referred to official documents. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: The documentation actually doesn't tell you to put any javascript files in the same directory as the Java classes. It is implied it's in the same directory as the rest of the project. In your project, you can probably remove the `index.js` file in `reactlibrary` if you still are importing `NativeModules` in your app

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, you custom package creation looks correct. Assuming the android code is also built before running the app (not just a package reload from the bundler), I would expect this to work.

You do not show an actual method request on ToastExample, so at which point did you determine that ToastExample is undefined? Did you use a debugger for this?

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { ToastExample } = NativeModules;

showTest = () => {
  ToastExample.show('test', ToastExample.SHORT);
}
```

If you'd set a breakpoint inside the showTest function, it's possible a debugger returns a ReferenceError when evaluating the 'ToastExample' inside a debug console, while the code runs fine. So did the code actually break at run-time?